# PHP how to read file if it doesn't belong to www-data

Tags: php, ftp, ubuntu-16.04, file-permissions

A whole day I'm searching the answer to my question with no success.

I have an directory, lets call it **csv**. I created a FTP user for my client to let him upload files there.

And now I want to read those files via PHP, but I can't because of the permissions problem. All the uploaded files have **0644** permissions, but I need atleast **0664** or to set file ownership to **www-data**. It's the only way I made it work. But everytime I need to change those files manually in order to work. How can I make it automatic?

Comment: Tell your client to put the correct permissions for the file or supply him with a file upload dialog. 2nd way is probably better, letting your clients with (possibly) no IT knowledge access your server can be **dangerous**.

Comment: add the user to www-data group. then 644 would suffice for reading.

Comment: Why don't you set the group on that directory to www-data and use setgid?

Comment: If your files have 644, they are readable by everyone on the system. So this is not the problem.

Comment: @mscho He obviously has to write to the file too since he says he needs atleast 664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

You could change the umask for the ftp server. Depending on the used server software, the "how to" varies. So you should check the documentation of the ftp server on how to use another umask.

The umask should be set to 0113 in your case. But I'm not absolutely shure on this.

**Option 2**

Another way could be, to set the sticky bit and the www-data user as the group for the target directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you brought me on the reight path. At the begining I was editing the wrong umask parameter in /etc/vsftpd.conf, that's why it didn't worked. But [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/805876) helped to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **chmod**. For example

```
chmod("test.csv",0755);
```

Comment: How should that work? If the PHP process has no access to these file, it cannot change the permissions